# Trying to do a query via REST with a space in it

Tags: query

I want to have a query that has a space in it for a multi-picklist.

However, everything I'm doing is either a malformed query or a bad request.

This is what I've got:

```
query?q=SELECT+Id,+LastModifiedDate,+AccountId,+Associated_Opportunity__c,+Name,+Site_Address__c,+Site_City__c,+Site_State__c,+Site_Zip_Code__c,+kW_DC__c,+Utility_Name_formula__c,+Utility_Account_Number__c,+RecordTypeId+FROM+Opportunity+WHERE+LastModifiedDate+>+2015-11-04T15:42:58Z+AND+RecordTypeId+IN+(‘recordidval’)+AND+FIELDICAREABOUT+includes+Firstname Secondname
```

FIELDICAREABOUT is a multi-picklist. Firstname Secondname is the search query I want to have. I've tried multiple forms of it:

('Firstname Secondname')

'Firstname Secondname'

Firstname+Secondname

in the URL and none of them seem to be working.

What's the correct format for a multi-picklist URL?

Comment: Spaces should be fine. Your browser should convert spaces to %20 which Salesforce can handle. One problem will throw an error will be that you need to have your includes in parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this doc on how to query multiselect picklist

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm

I tried the following query and works fine for me.

Use ; between your includes terms

> **FIELDICAREABOUT+includes+('Firstname;Secondname')**

```
/services/data/v34.0/query/?q=select+id,name,prao6308__Test_For_Multival__c+from+account+where+prao6308__Test_For_Multival__c+includes+('A;CV')
```

Response:

[image]